# How do I insert a shape onto an image and then play an audio file upon mouse hover or mouse click on that shape in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, html, microsoft

I love the feature MS PowerPoint offers where I can freehand draw a shape onto an image/video, then easily add an Action upon mouse hover or click of said shape. I need the same feature on my Wordpress website.

Note: I am unable to code and would love a front end or a simple Wordpress plugin solution. I have searched for a plugin and online for the past 3 days and found only visual animations, no audio options.

I have tried converting my PP presentation to HTML as well as embedding it using SlideShare, SlideBoom and Speaker Deck but the sound effect/audio file does not transfer over.

Any (constructive) input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not the common standard way of approaching of what you are trying to do. Thus you do not find any plugins in that direction. Several questions appear from a developer site, e.g. do you want to draw a different shape every time? If yes, one would have to build an advanced javascript canvas plugin, which can do that. Other ways also need coding knowledge. If you want to build a polygon shape, that is clickable, have a look at SVGs.

Comment: Thank you, yes it would be a different shape everytime. I will look into SVGs anyway. Thanks again @user3135691